# Is there a way to check breaking changes of a php package?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, package

At the moment I'm developing with Laravel and VueJs. I'm upgrading Laravel from 5.8 to 6.0 accordingly to the documentation.

It say's:

> "Next, examine any 3rd party packages consumed by your application and
> verify you are using the proper version for Laravel 6 support."

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3", # [1] Successfully upgraded to 7.2
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0", # [2] Successfully upgradedto 6.0
        "laravel/passport": "^9.3.2", # [3] Successfully upgradedto 9.3.2
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.4",
        "pragmarx/version": "^0.2.8",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.4",
        "santigarcor/laratrust": "5.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "orangehill/iseed": "^2.6",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.*"
    },
```

**Now my question:**

Is there a service (like a website) that I can use, to check if the package I want to update, got any breaking changes between my old and my new package version.

**For example:**
I want to upgrade `barryvdh-laravel-cors` from `0.11.0` to `2.0.4`.

The documentation of `barryvdh-laravel-cors` have section for "Upgrading from 0.x / barryvdh-laravel-cors".

Is there an easier way, than go into the documentation every time and look up the breaking changes by myself?

Answer (score 0):

Usually breaking changes managed by composer (by SemVer convention - https://semver.org/, all composer packages should follow it).
But,  Laravel before version 6 is not following semver, so you need to check all your laravel-related packages manually, by inspecting package docs.